# What's the relationship between size of integer and complex objects?

Tags: python, memory, sizeof, complex-numbers

I recently heard about Python integer cache. After having searched on internet, I have found this well-written article : http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation. It explains what I wanted to know about this subject.

In this article, it explains why a integer object is not only 16 or 32 bits wide, as in C. Indeed, Python needs to store the object header (because a `int` Python integer *is* an object) and the value of this integer (with `long` C type, so at least 32 bits according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

On my machine, I get :

```
>>> x = 5
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
12
```

Ok. So a Python `int` object is 12 bytes wide.

My question comes from a comparison between integer and complex sizes. I typed, on the same machine :

```
>>> z = 5 + 5j
>>> type(z)
<type 'complex'>
>>> sys.getsizeof(z);
24
```

I believe that `complex` is an object. So, as `int`, each `complex` object has to store its object header. But, if the header of a `int` plus its value equals 12, why does the header of `complex` (same size as `int`, I suppose !) plus its value (2 times the size of an integer ?) equals 24 ?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `complex` contains two floats, not two integers:

```
>>> import sys
>>> z = 5 + 5j
>>> z.imag
5.0
>>> z.real
5.0
>>> sys.getsizeof(z.imag)
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(z.real)
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(z)
24
```

You can see the `complexobject` source code [in the Python repo](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1a972140ab62/Objects/complexobject.c).

Comment: Ok. And [this file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c84f896e76e9/Include/complexobject.h) describes exactly what `Py_complex` type is. We can see the two real & imag fields. Many thanks !

Comment: @ryolait that's the header for the same file

Answer (score 1):

Its because of that complex numbers are represented as a pair of floating point number:

> An [imaginary literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals) yields a complex number with a real part of 0.0. Complex numbers are represented as a pair of floating point numbers and have the same restrictions on their range. To create a complex number with a nonzero real part, add a floating point number to it, e.g., (3+4j). Some examples of imaginary literals:

Comment: Without looking into the Python source code, you have found a good answer ;-) ! Thanks, Kasra !